# Desestructurar y asignar en una misma linea

Tags: typescript

Como puedo desestructurar un objeto  y asignarle las propiedades a otro objeto en una misma linea

```
feth... .then(res => {
const {data:{a,b,c,d}} = res.data;//res.data = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h....}
const ojb= {a,b,c,d}
algo(obj)
otro(obj)
})
```

Ya que res.data da propiedades que no se usaran como "creationDate" desestructuro las necesarias y las asigno a otro objeto, pero a medida que se avanza la api, tengo que cambiar eliminar o poner propiedades en ambas líneas. hay una manera de hacerlo en una misma linea,
algo como esto

```
const obj = {data:{a,b,c,d}} = res.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

haz la desestructuración que necesitas en la repuesta del fetch, y asigna las propiedades que necesitas a las variables:

```
feth... .then({a,b,c,d} => {
  const obj = {a,b,c}

  const obj2 = {d}

})
```

Comment: lo que quiero no es repetir propiedades , algo como esto const obj = {data:{a,b,c,d}} = res.data